# Strange UITableview reload animation behavior

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have implemented a UITableview with dynamic cell sizing and expandable cells and for the most part, this code handles the expansion/contraction well:

```
  public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
  {
    dataArray[indexPath.row].isExpanded = !dataArray[indexPath.row].isExpanded
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
  }
```

However, when the cell that this method is called on is even slightly off the screen at the top, when it is expanded/contracted, the UITableview reload is jumpy and causes the cell to fly in/out of the screen.  What is the best way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is not the right way to make a dynamic expanding/contracting height cell (also called an accordion cell). The correct way is to call `self.tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil)`.

Comment: For a downloadable example project, see https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p451dynamicTableContent2/AccordionCell/ViewController.swift

Comment: The way I implemented it with UITableViewAutomaticDimension makes it so that I need to pass a closure block to: performBatchUpdates.  However, when I do: `tableView.performBatchUpdates({
      self.reloadData()
    })`, I lose the animation when the cell collapses.

Comment: The downloadable project shows you how to do it. We have animation on collapse and expand.

Comment: I actually implemented the expandable cells in a much different way originally.  However, after looking through your code, I slightly changed my cells and now the expanding/collapsing works perfectly! Thank you!